# what is the meaning of this specific line of code? getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1

Tags: android, android-fragments

i was looking at some code about viewPager and Fragment, and i didn't understand this line given below:

```
getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1
```

Comment: That's the whole line or it assigns the result to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Above line means:

```
int yourValue;
if(getArguments() != null) {
    yourValue = getArguments().getInt("val");
} else {
    yourValue = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the [ternary operator](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm).

The expression evaluates to `getArguments().getInt("val")` as long as `getArguments()` returns a non-`null` value; otherwise, it yields `1`.

Answer (score 0):

its like:

`x==0? 2:1`

here first statement till `?` is the `if` statement..
if if statement is true that means if x==0 then take the value 2 else take the value 1

```
if(x==0)
{
value become 2
}
else
{
value become 1
}
```